# Why enhanced-for statement cannot infer the type of lambda?

Tags: java, lambda

`try-with-resource` statement can infer the type of lambda.

```
try (Closeable 最後に実行 = () -> System.out.print("終了")) {
    System.out.println("開始");
}
```

But `enhanced-for` statement can't.

```
Iterator<String> 繰り返し = Arrays.asList("いち", "に", "さん").iterator();
for (String 文字列 : () -> 繰り返し)   // compile error!
    System.out.println(文字列);
```

We must write like this.

```
Iterator<String> 繰り返し = Arrays.asList("いち", "に", "さん").iterator();
for (String 文字列 : (Iterable<String>)() -> 繰り返し)
    System.out.println(文字列);
```

Why?

Comment: How would the compiler know that you want the lambda to be an implementation of the `Iterable` interface. The `for` statement doesn't require an `Iterable`, so it cannot be inferred from there. JLS [14.14.2. The enhanced for statement ](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) says: *The type of the Expression must be `Iterable` **or an array type**.* That's more than the inference engine can handle.

Comment: @Andreas Any lambda expressions cannot be `String[]` type.  So javac can infer `Iterable<String>`.

Answer (score 1):

Try-with-resorce can infer because you have declared the expected result type:

```
try (Closeable 最後に実行 = () -> System.out.print("終了")) {
     ^^^^^^^^^
```

Javac know the target type from that variable assignment that this lambda should be converted to a `Closeable`. However in enhanced for there is no such target type information. There may be multiple target type:

- `Iterable<String>` of course
- `public interface StringIterable extends Iterable<String>`
- `public interface WeridIterable extends Iterable<String>`
- ...

There are arbitrary number of possible target types, so you must explicitly give it by using `(Iterable<String>)`, as you have done in try-with-resource case.

Comment: And also `String[]`.

Comment: @saka1029 How would you make a lambda into an array type?

Comment: @VinceEmigh Closeable yes does have arbitrary number of possible subtypes but you gave that explicitly in *ResourceSpecification* part, so compiler won't be confused.